# Rails, Devise, Rspec: Undefined method 'sign_in'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

I am trying to write Rspec tests in Rails, using Devise helper methods for signing in and out. The sign_in method is not working. However, it had been working earlier, before a slew of changes to the app.

Things I have tried:

- I am including the test helpers in Rspec.configure.
- Using Warden's login_as
- Clearing the Rails cache.
- Getting rid of Capybara to see if that were causing the issue
- I am not setting the session explicitly in my controller specs (e.g. no valid_session)

So far, no dice. What do I need to do differently to test my controllers with a signed-in user?

Error message:

```
 OrderItemsController GET #index renders the :index view
 Failure/Error: sign_in :admin
 NoMethodError:
      undefined method `sign_in' for #  <RSpec::ExampleGroups::OrderItemsController_2::GETIndex:0x00000102c002d0>
 # ./spec/controllers/order_items_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Controller Spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe OrderItemsController do
    before (:each) do
        admin = create(:admin)
        sign_in :admin
    end

    describe "GET #index" do
        it "renders the :index view" do
            get :index
            expect( response ).to render_template :index
        end
    end
end
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include ApplicationHelper
  config.include ControllersHelper
  config.include UsersHelper
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

end
```

Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0.beta'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'dotenv-rails'
    gem 'guard'
    gem 'guard-annotate'
    gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
    gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
    gem 'foreman'
end
```

factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

    factory :user do
        first                   { Faker::Name.first_name }
        last                    { Faker::Name.last_name }
        email                   { Faker::Internet.email }
        admin                   false
        password                "secrets1"
        password_confirmation   "secrets1"
        confirmed_at            Date.today

        factory :admin do
            admin               true
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade to RSpec 3 like I did? This is from [the RSpec 3 documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/directory-structure):

> Automatically Adding Metadata
>   RSpec versions before 3.0.0 automatically added metadata to specs based on
>   their location on the filesystem. This was both confusing to new users and not
>   desirable for some veteran users.
>
> In RSpec 3, this behavior must be explicitly enabled:
>
> ```
> ​# spec/rails_helper.rb
> RSpec.configure do |config|
>     config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
> end
> ```
>
> Since this assumed behavior is so prevalent in tutorials, the default
>   configuration generated by rails generate rspec:install enables this.
>
> If you follow the above listed canonical directory structure and have
>   configured infer_spec_type_from_file_location!, RSpec will automatically
>   include the correct support functions for each type.

After I add that configuration snippet, I no longer have to specify the spec type (e.g. `type: :controller`).

Answer (score 9):

If you need the `sign_in` method in a **request spec** file, then you should include this:

```
config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
```

Comment: Nice answer. And just to clarify, the line goes inside the block that starts with `RSpec.configure do |config|`

Answer (score 8):

I figured out a solution. I explicitly defined the controller's Describe block as a controller type.

```
describe OrderItemsController, :type => :controller do
```

I still don't understand why this code worked earlier but now needs this (seemingly redundant) explicit declaration. Regardless, I'd appreciate learning what happened here. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, helped me. I'm going from Rails 4 to 4.1. You? I'll check the controller test guides and if I find anything I will mention it here.

Comment: Still on Rails 4.0.3. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Think I found it. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

I can provide you an example (works for me - rspec / capybara / simplecov etc..)

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
 require 'capybara/rspec'
 require 'capybara/rails'

 RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

**spec/integration/user_flow_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'Verify contract' do
  # Create employee
  let(:employee) { create(:employee) }
  let (:book) { create(:book) }

  # Sign in employee before each test!
  before :each do
    login_as employee, scope: :user
  end

  scenario 'create book' do
    # Visit Index and click to create
    visit employee_books_path
    click_link 'Create'
    expect(current_path).to eq(employee_books_path)
  end
end
```

I hope it will be ok :) I think your problem is missing Warden test helpers...

Comment: Now it's saying undefined method 'get' and 'post', so I can't tell if your answer has bypassed my issue. Again, all of this worked earlier, it's just weird.

Comment: @steel, your comment here helped me to realize I was indeed in the same boat as you, and thus your answer worked for me too.

Comment: Showing your spec_helper helped me. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Devise helper in the file spec/spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For Rails 5 and Rspec 3 you need to add this into your spec_helper.rb

> config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller

Answer (score -1):

You can use login_as method instead like this:

```
# rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
   config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
end
```

In your spec file use:

```
#spec/integration/user_flow_spec.rb
before :each do
    employee = create(:employee)
    login_as employee, scope: :user
end
```

Comment: The `undefined method` error indicates the correct module(s) wasn't mixed in. Your solution, while it would work, does not address the original question.