# Rspec.NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test the admin user in my controller, but when I'm running the test, the shell returns an error :

```
  1) Posts GET /edit_post works for edit post
     Failure/Error: sign_in user
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec:
```

posts_spec.rb

```
  describe 'GET /edit_post' do
    it 'works for edit post' do
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      user.role == 'admin'
      sign_in user
    end
  end
```

***UPD***
this is rails_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: You need to provide the code that is causing this crash.

Comment: sorry, I forgot about it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails, Devise, Rspec: Undefined method 'sign\_in'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859653/rails-devise-rspec-undefined-method-sign-in)

Answer (score 0):

Have you included Devise's test helpers, to allow you to use `sign_in`?

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb or spec/spec_helper.rb or spec/support/devise.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

It's explained here:

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/file/README.md#Test_helpers

Comment: I know about solving but this is don't working.I update the question

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this so I added the following line to `test/test_helper.rb` and it worked for me.

`include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers`