# NoMethodError undefined method sign_in rspec devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

Given that I am trying to write a simple rspec test whilst using devise I seem to keep NoMethodError: undefined method sign_in I have the following setup but cannot seem to get around this. I did come across another similar question to this [Rails, Devise, Rspec: Undefined method 'sign_in'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859653/rails-devise-rspec-undefined-method-sign-in) and I a certain I have `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` enabled as shown in my snippet for my rails helper

**Spec Helper**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
end
```

**rails helper**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
#
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

**support/devise**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controllers
end
```

**controller_spec**

```
describe UsersController do
  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :admin)
    sign_in @user
  end

  context "HTML" do

    describe "GET index" do
      it "assigns all users as @users" do
        user = @user
        get :index, {}
        assigns(:user).should eq([user])
      end
    end
  end


end
```

I constantly keep getting:

Testing started at 10:15 AM ...

> NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for
>
> /home/trcdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/routing.rb:171:in
>   `method_missing' ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:4:in`
>   block (2 levels) in '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not showing it, so I'm guessing that it's not there. You need to `require "rails_helper"` in your `controller_spec`.